# obtener id y class al pulsar sobre un objeto

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsonarray

tengo un listado de usuarios, en cada row(usuario) hay varios div, el tema es que esos usuarios se mostraran desde un json, creando distintos div y class segun el json, luego tengo en cada usuario dos , uno para editar ese usuario y otro para "llamar"(ejecuta una funcion), el tema es que quiero que al pulsar sobre una img me de el id y la class de esa imagen, ya que si uso

```html
document.getElementById("editaruser").onclick=function(){loquesea}
```

no me serviría ya que tendrian todos los usuarios el mismo id y no funciona, pero si pongo byclass no funciona el .onclick, entonces lo que necesito es que cada usuario se creará con un id unico, y lo que necesito es un método para que al pulsar sobre un img me de su id...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener los valores del id y otros atributos de un elemento usando [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Por ejemplo al hacer click en un boton:

```js
function mostrarID(event) { 
  document.querySelector("p").innerText = event.target.id
}
```

```html
<button id= "boton" onclick="mostrarID(event)" >Click</button>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

si cada usuario le pongo un id al dibujo de editar y llamar, en cada uno de esos dibujos le pongo en la etiqueta
onClick="obtenerid(this);"

luego en la función js

```html
 function obtenerid(elemento)
{
 alert(elemento.id);
}
```

así obtengo el id de ese elemento